# Python-Detect a click on the minimize button

Tags: python, sendmessage, win32gui

I want to detect a click on any window's minimize button with win32gui.
I have a idea to use WM.NCHITTEST but I have no idea how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out.

The following snippet first waits for a right click and then get's the click positions(x and y axis) and then performs the hittest to know the type of area on which the click was performed:

```
    import win32gui, win32api
    previous_state = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)
    while True:
        a = win32api.GetKeyState(0x02)
        if a != previous_state:
            previous_state = a
            if a < 0:
                Clickx, Clicky = win32gui.GetCursorPos()
                window = win32gui.GetForegroundWindow()
                win32gui.SetForegroundWindow(window)
                WM_NCHITTEST_result = win32gui.SendMessage(window, 0x0084,"",Clickx)
                if WM_NCHITTEST_result == 8: # check if click is on the minimize btn 
                    # Do something here
```

Officialy the hittest is performed with:

```
                Clickx, Clicky = win32gui.GetCursorPos()
                WM_NCHITTEST_result = win32gui.SendMessage(window, 0x0084,"",Clickx)
```

and the result is checked if it was a minimize click:

```
                if WM_NCHITTEST_result == 8:
```